# Extension Methods and generics - How should I be doing this?

Tags: c#, generics, refactoring

I'm in the middle of overhauling some code and I hit a bit of a snag.

This is the method which I currently have, it needs reworking to support some structure changes:

```
/// <summary>
/// Recreates a dashboard control based off of its settings.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"> The type of control to be recreated. </typeparam>
/// <param name="settings"> The known settings needed to recreate the control.</param>
/// <returns> The recreated control. </returns>
public static T Recreate<T>(ISetting<T> settings) where T : new()
{
    T _control = new T();
    settings.SetSettings(_control);
    Logger.DebugFormat("Recreated control {0}", (_control as Control).ID);
    return _control;
}
```

ISetting is being removed completely in favor of an extension method known to _control.

So, I have now:

```
public static class RadControlExtensions
{
    public static RadDockZoneSetting GetSettings(this RadDockZone dockZone)
    {
        RadDockZoneSetting radDockZoneSetting = new RadDockZoneSetting(dockZone.UniqueName, dockZone.ID, dockZone.Skin, dockZone.MinHeight, 
            dockZone.HighlightedCssClass, dockZone.BorderWidth, dockZone.Parent.ID);

        return radDockZoneSetting;
    }

    public static RadTabSetting GetSettings(this RadTab tab, int index)
    {
        RadTabSetting radTabSetting = new RadTabSetting(tab.Text, tab.Value, index);
        return radTabSetting;
    }

    //Continued
}
```

The control that is being recreated is guaranteed to have this extension method (would be nice to enforce this, though.)

I'm now at:

```
public static T Recreate<T>() where T : new()
{
    T _control = new T();
    //Not right -- you can't cast a control to an extension method, obviously, but
    //this captures the essence of what I would like to accomplish.
    (_control as RadControlExtension).SetSettings();
    Logger.DebugFormat("Recreated control {0}", (_control as Control).ID);
    return _control;
}
```

What should I be looking into to support this, if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that every `_control` that gets passed will be a RadDockZone (or derived from RadDockZone) just do this:

```
T _control = new T();
(RadDockZone)_control.SetSettings();
Logger.DebugFormat("Recreated control ... //rest of code here
```

If it's not always going to be a RadDockZone, you'll need to do some type checking to get the right type to call the extension method.  I'm presuming, there, that you have a .SetSettings() extension method on all the possible Types that could be passed to your Recreate method.

Comment: The scenario is the ladder -- I'll try, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a simplistic solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your T to something that is supported by your extension method.

`(_control as RadDockZone).GetSettings`

Extension methods operate on a type they are not a type in the traditional sense.  The 'SomeFn(string this)'  makes your extension work on things that are strings which would be strings and anything derived from them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, just put a constraint on `T`:

```
public static T Recreate<T>() where T : RadControl, new() {
    // etc.
}
```

You might have to use double dispatch and define

```
public static RadControl GetSettings(this RadControl control) {

}
```

which will invoke the appropriate `GetSettings` method.

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a good common base until "WebControl" and extending WebControl with my method doesn't feel right. Going to look into AllenG's suggestion first and see if that feels right.

Answer (score 0):

No, Jason's answer is the cleaner way to go. The accepted solution killed the type safety and made use of generics pointless. You could switch to generic-less design (having a `RadControlFactory`) and had the job done.